# Request does not return results

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

there is a request to Postgres that works if executed in the database:

```
(select * from layout where layout.layout_id in(select distinct camera_layout.layout_id from camera_layout where camera_layout.camera_id in
(select c.camera_id  FROM object LEFT JOIN camera c on object.object_id = c.object_id WHERE object.region_id = ?)))
```

but if you make a request via @query native in Reposytory, an empty string is returned:

```
    @Query( value = "(select * from layout where layout.layout_id in (select distinct camera_layout.layout_id from camera_layout where camera_layout.camera_id in\n" +
            "(select c.camera_id  FROM object LEFT JOIN camera c on object.object_id = c.object_id WHERE object.region_id = :region)))",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List <Layout> filterRegion(@Param("region") Integer region);
```

why? I am sure that the parameters are passed, the layout list should return

Comment: I've compared the two statements in WinMerge, and can confirm they are nearly identical. What about that "\n" Character at the end of the first line in your second block? `... where camera_layout.camera_id in\n"`
Is that necessary?

Comment: "an empty string is returned" - does this mean you're checking it at some API level? Did you debug your application to confirm the `List <Layout>` that's returned is empty?

Comment: Also try to debug that statement or raise the logging-level output of your JPA/Repository layer - ideally you'll get that final statement which is generated 1:1 so you can copy and execute it in your SQL-Client to test it.

Comment: /n required , it just splits the request for clarity , it is not reflected at work

Comment: Turn on SQL logging. set org.hibernate.SQL to debug and org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder to trace and then check the SQL statement